# Espeak on anaconda windows 10

Tags: python, anaconda, espeak

I wanted to run a piece of code which uses espeak. I have installed espeak using `py-espeak-ng` on my anaconda environment. But when I run the code it shows me the following error:

```
'espeak' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

So I looked for answers and found that the solution to this was:

> Try adding the full path to your espeak installation

which I don't know how to do that. Can anyone explain me the procedure for this?

Comment: Have you tried just downloading espeak like normal, and then use (via `import os`) `os.system("espeak 'hello world'")`?

Comment: I just defined a function for espeak like this:                                                                            `def alarm(msg):
    global alarm_status
    global alarm_status2
    global saying

    while alarm_status:
        print('call')
        s = 'espeak "'+msg+'"'
        os.system(s)

    if alarm_status2:
        print('call')
        saying = True
        s = 'espeak "' + msg + '"'
        os.system(s)
        saying = False`